# Making a Date Calculator that add days to date

Tags: javascript, html

I have : Date 0 = start date Date 1 = result date (after adding number of days) NDays = number of days to be added

I need (js) to make:  Date0 + NDays = Date1 Help me pls, i have 0.1 code knowledge!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="reserve_form">

    <div id="pickup_date"><p><label class="form">Date 0 :</label><input type="text date" value="10/15/1555" class="textbox" id="pick_date" name="pickup_date" onchange="cal()"</p></div>

    <div id="dropoff_date"><p><label class="form">Date 1 :</label><input type="date" class="textbox" id="drop_date" name="dropoff_date" onchange="cal()"/></p></div>

    <div id="numdays"><label class="form"> NDays :</label><input type="text" class="textbox" id="numdays2" name="numdays"/></div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Benjamin recommended Moment, which is an absolutely awesome library to manipulate dates and times. However, the DOM manipulation is not covered by Moment. You need to query the DOM, listen to events, and update the DOM in response to them.

If we deconstruct the task at hand, we need to

- render three fields, in the simplest case, three inputs,
- in the inputs that represent start date and extra data to add, we need to establish [event listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) that would listen to "change" events and pick up the values of these two fields to calculate the end date,
- for the third input that should show the end date, we need to change its value as often as the first two inputs are changed and the end date actually can be calculated.

We can think of the HTML part as of just three inputs:

```
<input id="start" type="date">
<input id="inc" type="number">
<input id="result" type="date">
```

The simplest solution looks like this:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const start = document.getElementById('start');
  const inc = document.getElementById('inc');
  const result = document.getElementById('result');

  const updateEndDate = () => {
    const startDate = new Date(start.value);
    const addDays = Number(inc.value);

    if (!isNaN(startDate) && !isNaN(addDays)) {
      const days = startDate.getDate(); // <- returns the day component of the date (as opposed to weekday)
      const endDate = new Date(startDate);

      endDate.setDate(days + addDays);
      result.value = endDate;
    }
  };

  start.addEventListener('change', updateEndDate);
  inc.addEventListener('change', updateEndDate);
});
```

You can [look at how this code works on Codepen](https://codepen.io/rishatmuhametshin/pen/ZVNZpz?editors=1010) and you're absolutely welcome to fork it, change it, play with it as much as you like. Let's walk through the code a bit.

First, each DOM element can fire *DOM events*. We can write code that listens to these events and runs *event listeners* — functions that we define and control. So we add two event listeners: one to `start` input field that hold the start date in date format (because the type of this field is "date"), and one to `inc` input field that represents extra days to be added.

Then, we declare a function that will be executed every time a "change" event is fired on either `start` or `inc` input field. We call this function `updateEndDate` because that's its purpose. You can call it differently, of course.

Finally, inside the `updateEndDate` function, we do three things: get values of `start` and `inc` fields and turn them into a date and a number respectively; we check if these are actually valid values; and we calculate the new (end) date.

A piece that might be most confusing is this one:

```
const days = startDate.getDate();
const endDate = new Date(startDate);

endDate.setDate(days + addDays);
```

So the [`Date#getDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) method returns the "day" component of a date. If a date is "October 10, 2000", then this method will return 10. If it's "January 17, 1990", the returned value will be 17.

Then, we create a new instance of Date object, `endDate`, that is identical to `startDate`. This is not necessarily important in this case, but generally it is recommended to work with date in this manner because dates in Javascript are *mutable*. Calling methods, especially ones that are called "set-something", would change the value of the instance, and oftentimes you may not want that.

So, yes, the `endDate`. The last thing we do is we call [`Date#setDate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) on it. Imagine that the start date is January 17, 2019, and you want to add 50 extra days. If we just add 50 to 17, the end date is going to be January 67, 2019, right? Well, that's one thing that Javascript does for us: once a date is updated (a "set-something" is called on it), it gets recalculated in a way that makes sense. So it's going to be March 8 instead.

I really do hope this answer helps you figure out what's up in there, and I wish you the best of luck learning Javascript. So, yep, check out the [codepen](https://codepen.io/rishatmuhametshin/pen/ZVNZpz?editors=1010) and wish you best of luck!

Comment: Thank you @rml , you've been of great help really, after your detailed explanation i was able to build uppon your provided code and made a nice app to help my gaming community.  I hope i can fast learn some coding ,its never too late!

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript details are commented in the demo

```js
/* 
Reference the form bind the change event to it. It will call
function calc() when change event triggers...
*/
document.forms[0].onchange = calc;

function calc(e) {
  // Collect all references to this form
  var ui = this.elements;
  
  // Get the values from both inputs as numbers
  var begin = ui.init.valueAsNumber;
  var cease = ui.term.valueAsNumber;

  // Convert them into milliseconds then subtract begin from cease
  var diff = (new Date(cease)) - (new Date(begin));
  
  /*
  The value of the output is...
  if diff is NaN then output is 0...
  else if diff is less than 0 then output is 0...
  else divide diff by 8.64x10⁷ (total ms in a day)
  */
  ui.days.value = isNaN(diff) ? 0 : diff < 0 ? 0 : diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <form id="form" onsubmit='return false'>

    <label>Date 0: </label><input id="init" name="init" type="date"><br><br>
    <label>Date 1: </label><input id="term" name="term" type="date"><br><br>

    <label>Days: </label><output id="days" name="days">0</output>

  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into https://momentjs.com . Include the moment library by adding the following script tag just before the `</body>` tag.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```